Flutter resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false Not Working
My dialogbox keeps sliding up when i use the textfield and the keyboard slides up. I set resizeToAvoidBottomInset to false in my scaffold but it doesn't work. I did some testing apps to see if it works, and it did work every time when i didn't put the text inside a dialog box. So i thought maybe the dialog box has default settings that overrides my scaffold setting but i couldn't find anything by researching.
I tried to put the scaffold in the main.dart file instead of an external one but it didn't work. Chat gpt told me to use padding but it didnt'work
here is the code for the AlerDialog
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:school_manager/util/button.dart';
import 'package:school_manager/vars.dart';
import 'package:school_manager/todolist.dart';

class DialogBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback stateSet;
  final myController;
  DialogBox({
    super.key,
    required this.stateSet,
    required this.myController,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: swatch,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      content: Container(
        height: 114,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: myController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: "Add a new to do task",
                  hintStyle:
                      TextStyle(color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 54, 54, 54))),
              enableSuggestions: false,
              autocorrect: false,
            ),
            Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end, children: [
              MyButton(
                  text: "Save",
                  onPressed: () {
                    todo.add([myController.text, false]);
                    stateSet();
                    myController.clear();
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }),
              MyButton(
                  text: "Cancel",
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  })
            ])
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



I found this code snapshot in Dialog witch is the super class of the AlertDialog, as you can see, effectivePadding will be changed when keyboard is showing, see more about MediaQuery
